# taming the glutTimerFunc

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am using the **GLUT timer function** in a scenario slightly more complex than covered in tutorials and FAQs. Simplified abstract is the following:

If a ***condition*** is met, screen has to redraw timely and in short intervals. If a condition isn't met, it means the re-display is controlled by other mechanisms, therefore the timer function shouldn't stay in the way by repeating the work already being done otherwise. As it cannot be ***deregistered***, does it have to be programmatically slowed down and put out of purpose? Is the following code snippet a proper way of implementing it in **C**?

```
#define SLOW 1000
#define FAST 100
GLboolean condition = GL_FALSE

//   {   …   } //mechanism for setting the condition

void update (int val)
{
if(val)glutPostRedisplay();
return;
}

void timerCallback(int par)
{
if(condition == GL_TRUE){
  update(1);
  glutTimerFunc(FAST, timerCB, FAST); 
  }else {
  glutTimerFunc(SLOW, timerCB, SLOW);
  }
return;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply avoid registering the callback when `condition` is false, instead of making it run more slowly. From `glutTimerFunc` documentation:

> Unlike most other callbacks, timers only occur once.

Then, when the `condition` becomes true again, register the callback, from the code that sets `condition` to true. Be careful not to re-register an already scheduled callback - you should keep another flag that tells whether the callback is currently registered or not, as the docs says that "you cannot deregister a timer callback".

Code example:

```
GLboolean isCallbackRegistered = GL_FALSE;

void timerCallback(int par)
{
  if(condition == GL_TRUE){
    update(1);
    glutTimerFunc(FAST, timerCB, FAST); 
  } else {
    isCallbackRegistered = GL_FALSE;
  }
}

// ... the code the changes the value of `condition`
condition = GL_TRUE;
if(isCallbackRegistered != GL_TRUE) {
  isCallbackRegistered = GL_TRUE;
  glutTimerFunc(FAST, timerCB, FAST); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope it is also clear from my code that I've read the documentation, about "timers occurring only once". Please pardon my using inappropriate term for **deregistering**. If I got you right, in the code snippet after  `else` should say `;`  ?

Comment: Yes, but that's probably not enough. Updated the answer with code.

Comment: Thanks, you probably meant `GLboolean isCallbackRegistered = GL_FALSE`, not `int isCallbackRegistered = GL_FALSE` in line 1 of your code - as you haven't reacted, I assumed freedom of editing it myself. The rest of your code seems to work well against several independent sources assigning `GLboolean condition = GL_TRUE`, possibly attempting to register the callback without prior checking if it is already registered, IMHO. 'GLboolean condition' has to have the same scope as 'GLboolean isCallbackRegistered'.